# Can't update JAVA_HOME in Ionic

Tags: java-8, ionic2

So i have already updated my JDK to a version 8.0 or greater and I already confirmed it on the terminal with `java -version`. However when I run the command ionic build android, it still has the `JAVA_HOME` set to the previous JDK, the 7.0. I did already change it in the `/etc/environment` and yes, afterwards I used `source /etc/environment/`.

Anyone know how to update the `JAVA_HOME` for Ionic?

Comment: which environment? ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake in the path set to JAVA_HOME.

I changed it to the following

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle